# MAX/MIN giving me wrong values in mysql

Tags: mysql, max, min

I am trying to get the `MAX()` or the `MIN()` value of a dataset.

**Sample data:**

```
equipment_id, value, updateTimestamp

77, 81.57, 2013-05-28 12:00:00
77, 89.56, 2013-05-28 13:00:00
77, 92.76, 2013-05-28 14:00:00
77, 94.15, 2013-05-28 15:00:00
77, 97.66, 2013-05-28 16:00:00
77, 95.07, 2013-05-28 17:00:00
77, 95.15, 2013-05-28 18:00:00
77, 92.90, 2013-05-28 19:00:00
77, 96.16, 2013-05-28 20:00:00
77, 99.56, 2013-05-28 21:00:00
77, 101.67, 2013-05-28 22:00:00
77, 103.09, 2013-05-28 23:00:00
77, 103.34, 2013-05-29 00:00:00
77, 100.24, 2013-05-29 01:00:00
77, 99.66, 2013-05-29 02:00:00
77, 99.86, 2013-05-29 03:00:00
77, 98.38, 2013-05-29 04:00:00
77, 97.97, 2013-05-29 05:00:00
77, 98.06, 2013-05-29 06:00:00
77, 96.23, 2013-05-29 07:00:00
77, 95.92, 2013-05-29 08:00:00
77, 98.89, 2013-05-29 09:00:00
77, 97.73, 2013-05-29 10:00:00
77, 85.95, 2013-05-29 11:00:00
77, 73.72, 2013-05-29 12:00:00
77, 62.60, 2013-05-29 13:00:00
```

The following query will give me back `100.24`

```
SELECT dv.equipment_id, ROUND(MIN(dv.value), 2) as value     
FROM b_datavalues dv
INNER JOIN b_equipment e ON e.equipment_id = dv.equipment_id
INNER JOIN b_datacenter d ON d.datacenter_id = e.datacenter_id
WHERE dv.equipment_id IS NOT NULL
AND dv.updateTimestamp BETWEEN '2013-05-28 11:45:00' and '2013-05-29 14:30:00'
AND d.name = 'rr'
AND e.name = 'hygrometer'
```

The correct answer should in fact be `62.60`. For max I get a value of `99.86`. It would appear that `MIN()` and `MAX()` are evaluating the first number only. Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value appears to be stored as a string, rather than as a number.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT dv.equipment_id, ROUND(MIN(cast(dv.value as decimal(5, 2))), 2) as value
```

Comment: float isn't a type available to cast to. decimal is, however. `SELECT dv.equipment_id, ROUND(MAX(cast(dv.value as DECIMAL(5,2))), 2) as value` worked for me. thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @austin . . . My bad.  In MySQL, you can just add 0 (`+ 0`) to convert to a number.  The `decimal()`, though is standard SQL, which I prefer when reasonable.